# Laravel Forms - Fill a Multiple Select Input to View

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a tricky situation here.

I have an Edit form where I can fill the existing values when I'm editing an index. (I pass a Model Object in the controller). It works for every input field, but I need to fill a certain Multiple Select field which I don't know how to do it. I tried passing this specific value in the object, either as array (which contains the IDs of each selectable value) which crashes the view or as a json string using json_encode. I read an article here where the person accomplish this but it's done with a many-to-many relationship table, but the value I need to fill doesn't come from the table.

Resulting Object using dd()

```
Contact {#408 ▼
  +table: "contacts"
  #dates: array:1 [▼
    0 => "deleted_at"
  ]
  +fillable: array:5 [▼
    0 => "nombre"
    1 => "apellido"
    2 => "cargo"
    3 => "empresa_id"
    4 => "groups"
  ]
  #casts: array:5 [▼
    "nombre" => "string"
    "apellido" => "string"
    "cargo" => "string"
    "empresa_id" => "integer"
    "groups" => "array"
  ]
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:9 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "nombre" => "redacted"
    "apellido" => "redacted"
    "cargo" => "redacted"
    "empresa_id" => 2
    "created_at" => "2017-03-09 20:30:19"
    "updated_at" => "2017-11-29 17:30:55"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "groups" => "["2","3","4"]"
  ]
  #original: array:9 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "nombre" => "redacted"
    "apellido" => "redacted"
    "cargo" => "redacted"
    "empresa_id" => 2
    "created_at" => "2017-03-09 20:30:19"
    "updated_at" => "2017-11-29 17:30:55"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "groups" => "["2","3","4"]"
  ]
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
  #dateFormat: null
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #forceDeleting: false
```

Multiple Select Form.

```
{!! Form::label('groups', 'Grupos:') !!} </br>
{!! Form::select('groups', $groups, null, ['data-actions-box' => 'true', 'multiple'=>'multiple']) !!}
```

If more information is needed I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by transforming the array elements to *int* before passing it to json_encode.